# Is there a fix for 'scrollTo' jquery function not working in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, firefox

Hello and happy holidays to you all,

I was just about to move forward with development of my new site, when I decided to try it in Firefox. Until now I was only testing in Chrome, Safari and on phones and everything is perfect.
But, when I open the web in Firefox it completly skips the intro which is initiated mostly by jquery, and also doesnt animate in navigation which is also put in place by jquery.

I went back to the earliest JSFiddle I have and it also does not work in Firefox, but works perfectly everywhere else.

[Here is the fiddle fullscreen result](http://jsfiddle.net/ehxptLft/4/embedded/result/)

[And here is the fiddle design view](http://jsfiddle.net/ehxptLft/4/)

I am using `scrollTo` to navigate on the page..

What I do is have a container that is three times the viewport width

```
#container {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 300%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

and then this container contains 3 "pages" boxes each has 100% of viewport width

```
.box {
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;/*
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: red;*/
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

The reason it is 33.33% is because the container is the parent so each page takes 33.33% out of the 100% of the parent width which is actually 300% of viewport width..

Then there is a fixed menu with buttons inside

```
#naw_wrap{
  width:100%;
  height:30px;
  background-color:green;
  position: fixed;
  z-index:2;
  top:50%;
}
```

The buttons on click use `scrollTo` function to move to the desired `.box` page

```
function goToBox(boxid){
  $('body').animate({
    scrollLeft: $(boxid).offset().left+'px'
  }, 500);
};
```

Also on document ready function I use the function above to scroll instantly over to the "home" page. Now of this works in Firefox

I hope this is now more acceptable. Just tested it in Opera and it works there as well. Could you possible look into it now and be able to tall what is causing it to malfunction in Firefox?

Comment: Any errors in console? Always the first place to start.

Comment: nothing in console. just nothing is animating. :/ im gonna put in some code since im on hold. gimme a few minutes

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with one of these?
`Using //@ to indicate sourceMappingURL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead jquery-2.0.2.min.js:1` and `window.controllers is deprecated. Do not use it for UA detection. nsHeaderInfo.js:412`?

Comment: Even better: make a minimal example. Take out parts of your code until the problem doesn’t appear anymore, then post what you had just before that. (You might even solve the problem in the process!)

Comment: aight guess I'll be back tomorrow :/ I'm rather a noob regarding optimalization/izolation this is gonna take me a while. Thank you for the tips. Also @VáclavZeman I have no clue why those two are being thrown since I am linking the jquery 202 directly from jquery's website..

Comment: @U2744SNOWFLAKE would this fiddle help http://jsfiddle.net/ehxptLft/4/ ? its the earliest I have. It has the core functionality and it is also not working in Firefox. I'm pretty hopeless

Comment: @U2744SNOWFLAKE I edited the whole thing, with much more simple fiddle could you possibly put it off hold now?

Answer (score 0):

Had to change the function selector from `'body` to `'body,html'` as apparently it works differently in Firefox.